# How do I reserve space for std::vector/std::string?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm looking for a way that prevents std::vectors/std::strings from growing in a given range of sizes (say I want to assume that a string will hold around 64 characters, but it can grow if needed). What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `.reserve()` member function. The [standard docs at the SGI site](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html)  say

> [4] Reserve() causes a reallocation manually. The main reason for
>   using reserve() is efficiency: if you know the capacity to which your
>   vector must eventually grow, then it is usually more efficient to
>   allocate that memory all at once rather than relying on the automatic
>   reallocation scheme. The other reason for using reserve() is so that
>   you can control the invalidation of iterators. [5]
>
> [5] A vector's iterators are invalidated when its memory is
>   reallocated. Additionally, inserting or deleting an element in the
>   middle of a vector invalidates all iterators that point to elements
>   following the insertion or deletion point. It follows that you can
>   prevent a vector's iterators from being invalidated if you use
>   reserve() to preallocate as much memory as the vector will ever use,
>   and if all insertions and deletions are at the vector's end.

That said, as a general rule unless you *really know* what is going to happen, it may be best to let the STL container deal with the allocation itself.

Comment: Well I didn't mean 'standard' as in C++ standard, I meant standard as is standard docs for the STL -- that's where we've all been going for a decade+.

Comment: Your definition of "all" is broken.

Comment: So where do you go for online STL docs?  Google always comes back to that very SGI site if you query eg 'stl vector resize'.  But I am sure you have a better search engine than me.

Comment: Google is not an expert on C++ terminology, and well if you search for "STL" references then yes you're going to get "STL" references. For C++ Standard Library docs, I'd suggest "C++ vector resize", but the top results are a bit rubbish. Instead, get a good reference from [this list](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Comment: There is a saying: "If you're in a hole, stop digging." Methinks your problem is that vector is in fact an STL objects, not a standard library object, hence the SGI reference in my initial answer.  See e.g. the beginning of the Wikipedia article on 'c++ vector': "Vector is a class template in the C++ Standard Template Library, which functions like a dynamic array..."  Ok?

Comment: It is both. The STL contains a data type called "vector", and there is also the C++ Standard Library `std::vector`, which was based on the same. Feel free to read the C++ Standard one day: a _far_ more authoritative reference than some load of gubbins from Wikipedia, clearly. That's _your_ problem in thinking that they are one and the same.

Comment: I think STL's version predates the inclusion in the C++ standard.  Anyway, the bickering is moot as with current C++ the difference between standard library, STL and more is pretty washed out. C++ in 2011 is a lot more fun than it was in 1991 when I started to use and g++ barely had template support.

Comment: Correct, STL's vector predates `std::vector`. Hard for `std::vector` to based on it otherwise! And, yes, I know what C++ was like in 1991.

Answer (score 2):

You reserve space for `vector` and `string` by their `reserve(size_type capacity)` member function. But it doesn't prevent it from anything :). You're just telling it to allocate at least that much of uninitialized memory (that is, no constructors of your type will be called) and resize to more if needed.

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
v.reserve(100); //no constructor of MyClass is called
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    v.push_back(MyClass()); // no reallocation will happen. There is enough space in the vector
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For vector:

```
std::vector<char> v;
v.reserve(64);
```

For string:

```
std::string s;
s.reserve(64);
```

Where's your C++ Standard Library reference got to?

Answer (score 0):

Both of them have member function called `reserve` which you can use to reserve space.

```
c.reserve(100); //where c is vector (or string)
```